# SQLCODE= -9999 during select in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, sqlcode

First time working with DB2, and I'm getting an occasional failed sql state with SQLCODE=-9999 from various stored procs. The frequency varies, and today has been fairly frequent, so I'd figured while I'm waiting for it to work again I'd try to find out what's going on. Google has failed to help me dertermine what the error code means, so I'm hoping someone on here has seen it and can clue me in.

One of the other developers has told me this only occurs on the test enviroment, but is not seen on the integration enviroment. None of the stored procs I am using have been promoted to the integration enviroment, so I'm assuming this issue has been seen before and ignored since it is "only" test.

Here's the error message:

```
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [08506] [IBM][DB2] SQL30108N  
A connection failed but has been re-established. Special register settings 
might have been replayed. Host name or IP address of the 
new connection: "192.168.252.156". Service name or port number of the 
new connection: "446".  Reason code: "1".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Info Center page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30108n.html) on this error (link is for Linux/Unix/Windows v10.1, since you don't mention a platform), and as it mentions in the message, the connection failed for "some reason", and it was re-established.

There's not a whole ton of help on the error page:

> **User response**
>
> The application is responsible for re-building session resources. The
>   application must re-issue all the operations that have been rolled
>   back.

Comment: I created functionality to detect this error and retry the call, which seems to handle the issue most of the time. I'm assuming the issue is with the server.